# Using Private API to monitor application state

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've been trying to use private APIs from `LSApplicationWorkspace` to monitor another application's state.(Just for fun, no intention of submitting to AppStore).I try to add a `LSApplicationWorkspaceObserver` to `LSApplicationWorkspace`, and register for state change notifications.

```
@interface MyObserver : NSObject<LSApplicationWorkspaceObserverProtocol>
- (void)applicationStateDidChange:(NSArray *)arg1;
@end
[[LSApplicationWorkspace defaultWorkspace] addObserver:[[MyObserver allocl] init]];
[[LSApplicationWorkspace defaultWorkspace] sendApplicationStateChangedNotificationsFor:@"com.apple.AppStore"];
```

By checking `[LSApplicationWorkspace defaultWorkspace].remoteObserver.currentObserverCount` I can see `MyObserver` is added successfully.But the `applicationStateDidChange` callback is never called.Any idea why?

PS:Running on iOS10.2.1.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this?